# VBA-SQL How to Set Dynamic Data Source

Tags: excel, vba

I've the following set of codes to copy data from a closed workbook, in this example, Book1.xlsx. In real scenario, the file path is dynamic.

```
Sub copydatafromMainWS()

    Dim Filename As String
    Dim wss As Worksheet
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\PC\Documents\"
        
        If .Show = True Then
            Filename = .SelectedItems(1)
            Debug.Print Filename
        End If
    End With
    
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, rst As ADODB.Recordset
    
    Set wss = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dart")
    
    wss.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Clear

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                       & "Data Source=Filename;" _  '>>> *Here is the problem*
                       & "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"
    
    conn.Open
    
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    rst.ActiveConnection = conn
    rst.Source = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
    rst.Open
    
    wss.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst
    
    rst.Close
    conn.Close
        
End Sub
```

The problem lies on the file path of the selected file i.e. Filename (C:\Users\PC\Documents\Book.xlsx). Filename does not seem to be recognised or captured.

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try.

```vb
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
         & "Data Source=" & Filename & ";" _  '>>> *change*
         & "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"
```